# IPN / PDT PAYPAL Headache

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, eclipse-pdt, receipt

UPDATED!

I managed to get a dynamic receipt using PDT, screenshot here: http://pastebin.com/4RcTdHKd which is generated from my pdt.php here: http://pastebin.com/4RcTdHKd

Now is the question how do I manipulate the variable tx to get whats needed, for example the transaction ID to dynamically show / or not show downloadable audio/video content?

Is it a good idea to on this .php have all (there aret THAT many files) downloadable files available, but as input type=hidden and just have some condition or IF statements that check if the product id = downloadable hidden id?

I got some tips using the following code to access but havent solved it yet:
$tx_token = $_GET['tx'];

Answer (score 2):

First, IPN and PDT are two completely different systems.  PDT is used more for a return page, to create a dynamic receipt.  IPN is used more for updating your shopping cart, database, or system.  You do know what your IPN and PDT script to be the same page, as this can cause some problems.  You will want to have an IPN script separate from your PDT script.

As for getting the transaction id, you can use something similar to this:

$tx_token = $_GET['tx'];

And then you can just echo out the response on to the page.  You can find sample of a PDT PHP script at https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216627 that may better help you, or give you a working example to build off of.  There are a few different ways you can incorporate this into your wordpress site, all which depend on your current set up and which option works best for you.  Some merchants use plugins and use the code with their plugins, and others use an iframe and have the PDT script within an iframe.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Ive actually managed to get the receipt using PDT now and have styled the output so it looks neat: http://snag.gy/nvGIu.jpg with this PDT.php: http://pastebin.com/4RcTdHKd I think that my customer will handle her "filing" on her own, meaning I dont need to update any databases. Do I still need IPN and another separate script too? Also, is it possible in this pdt.php to output the tx, take whats needed (the id of the products) and somehow show the respective downlodable content? How to do this, with IF statements?

Comment: Also I dont really wanna use a plugin since they often cost money and im underpaid =) and also if u do you dont rally learn anything as a developer, its better I think to try to do the things yoursel, even if you dont understand it all. That way you can help youself/others in the future with same issues